# Why doesn't my layout resize using a Graphical Layout?

Tags: android-layout, android

I have added supports-screens to manifest, all UI elements values are in dip.

Why then I'm changing screen type in Graphical Layout my layout doesn't re-sizes?

I'm using LinearLayout, maybe better way is RelativeLayout?

Please help;

My Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="#000000">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
              android:textSize="20dip"
              android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Login" />        
    </RelativeLayout>   

   <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:background="@drawable/background"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">        

        <ImageView          
        android:id="@+id/Image"
            android:layout_width="280dip"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dip"  
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_height="35dip"   
            android:src="@+drawable/logo_big"/>
    <EditText       
      android:id="@+id/LoginName"
      android:hint="Email"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dip"   
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dip"        
      android:paddingLeft="20dip"
      android:paddingRight="20dip"     
      android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
    <EditText   
      android:hint="Password"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dip"   
      android:inputType="textPassword"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dip"        
      android:paddingLeft="20dip"
      android:paddingRight="20dip"       
      android:password="true"
      android:id="@+id/Password"/>          
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/LogIn"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="45dip"  
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dip" 
      android:text="@+string/LogIn"/>
    <TextView       
      android:id="@+id/TextView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textSize="18dp"
      android:text="@+string/DontHaveAnAccount"/>           
    <Button     
      android:id="@+id/SingUpNow"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
      android:layout_height="45dip"   
      android:src="@+drawable/gray_button"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dip"       
      android:background="@+drawable/primary_button"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:text="@+string/SingUpNow"/>           
    <Button 
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"   
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="45dip"   
      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dip"       
      android:id="@+id/ForgotYourPassword"
      android:background="@+drawable/secondary_button"
      android:text="@+string/ForgotYourPassword"/>  
      </LinearLayout>       
</LinearLayout>
```

Help;

Comment: Show us the XML of the activity, and maybe a screenshot of your res folder

Comment: can u show the added supports-screens to manifest

Answer (score 0):

This tips maybe help you...

> Avoid the use of graphical layout, just check you code there will be some hard code value         or maybe there Absolute Layout..
>
> To re-size the screen layout use Relative Layout... that will be fit for all screen..

Comment: Can you paste here your XML code, which is generated by graphical layout designing..